# Ejabberd mod_mam error

Tags: mysql, ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I am using ejabberd 17.01 at ubuntu server also using mysql . I can see offline messages in table  'spool' and last activity in 'last' table . Bu cant see chatting messages. What is wrong i didnt understand ? i check all the tables but there is no saved data !

Thank you

ejabberd.yml

```
mod_mam:
  default: always
  iqdisc: one_queue
  request_activates_archiving: true
  assume_mam_usage: true
  cache_size: 1000
  cache_life_time: 3600
  db_type: sql
```

Comment: YAML is indentation sensitive

Comment: i corrected but still same :(

Comment: `archive` table is empty? Any errors in error.log/crash.log?

Comment: yes archive table is empty and ejabberd.log  there is no error i will check now crash and error log

Comment: there is no error other log files

Comment: just see that warning when ejabberd service restarting in ejabberd.log file          2017-02-09 10:29:24.779 [warning] <0.39.0>@ejabberd_config:emit_deprecation_warning:1393 Module mod_http_bind is deprecated, use mod_bosh instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `request_activates_archiving` and `assume_mam_usage` options, they are not needed anyway when `default` is `always`.